# Insert one element in a matrix cell

Tags: matlab, cell

I write that code:

```
final_results = {};
for eva = 1:N
        final_results{eva,1} = .....;
        final_results{eva,2} = .....;
        final_results{eva,3} = .....;
        if eva == N
           final_results{1,4} = ....;
        end
end
```

But output is a cell of dimension Nx4 in which the fourth column contain the number I put in `final_results{1,4}` and the other are []. How I can put only `final_results{1,4}` without obtain []?

Comment: First, you forgot `for` in `for eva = 1:N`. Now, the code is doing exactly what you ask for: for each value of `eva`, fill three columns of `final_result`. At the last iteration, add something in column 4: this will create a fourth column in cell `final_result`, initialized with empty arrays. If you don't want that, replace with `final_result{3*N+1}=...` and you will get a cell array with exactly 3N+1 non-empty values. Of course, the cell array will have been flattened into to a (cell) column vector

Comment: The error now is: Attempt to grow array along ambiguous dimension.

Comment: Indeed, it worked with Matlab 2014a but does an error with Matlab 2107b. The cell array has to be manually flattened first with `final_result=final_result(:);`. The following sample code works in newer releases of Matlab: `N=10; C=cell(N,3); C=C(:); C{3*N+1}=2;`